# Will I burn bridges if I reject a job offer after accepting but find a replacement for them?

Tags: job-offer

I accepted(but haven't signed contract) a job offer but I cannot go to anymore. Will I burn bridges with the company if I do this but I tell them I have a person that is a suitable replacement? Will this damage my reputation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retracting acceptance of a Job Offer without burning bridges](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3844/retracting-acceptance-of-a-job-offer-without-burning-bridges)

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the reason you cannot go there anymore, whether you will burn bridges.

I wouldn't suggest another person as a suitable replacement, however, as it is a common scam in some parts of the world to do exactly as you describe in order to get someone in who simply doesn't know what they are doing, or worse.

Comment: +1, all depends on the reason. I once did that but I stated the reason which was valid: Company is two hours away. We still contacted each other months later (no bridges were burned)

Comment: @Sandra I am wondering how it was perceived as valid? Did you only learn of the company's location after you accepted the offer?

Comment: @Babyburger We both knew from the beginning that my commute is far, they just accepted the fact that I changed my mind a while after accepting the offer.

Answer (score -4):

No it will not unless you signed a contract. They should understand. If they do not understand, then they are a bad company, then you should be happy not working for them.

Comment: Good answers should offer support or reasoning for why your solution is correct. Any other user could say "Yes, it will burn bridges, even if you haven't signed a contract. They won't understand." and readers would not be able to judge which answer makes more sense.

Comment: @DavidK I added my reasoning