# What to do- Job offer reduced

Tags: salary, job-offer

So basically I got offered a job verbally and was told that at the interview that they would like to offer me the position. They even introduced me to everyone in the team saying I will join the team in a couple of weeks.

They asked me to wait for a couple of weeks to get the paper work done. I contacted them in a couple of weeks and they reduced the offer because they said that they did not get the permission for what they originally offered. Not only that, they said they dont really need me but are just agreeing to keep me in board in somewhat of a good will gesture. They also said that if I find another job I should go for it. I asked them some time to think about it and then emailed them to ask them for a written offer to which they did not respond since a day. Can someone tell me what is it that they are trying to do and whether I should consider working for this place?

Actually im an international student and I am just about to graduate. Thus I could need the job and the employer told me in the second interview that I wont be able to get a job anywhere else

Comment: Run. Run, Run - and get away - you got off lucky

Comment: We are unfortunately not psychics, we can't know their intentions or whether the red flags this action creates are deal breakers for you.  Voting to close.

Comment: @Orange Although in your shoes I would consider their action to be a huge red flag and would be very cautious in my dealings with them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reducing the salary after job offer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31326/reducing-the-salary-after-job-offer)

Comment: Do you really want to work at a place that flat out told you they don't need you and encouraged you to look elsewhere? Do you need a job, or are you just looking to move?

Comment: Actually im an international student and I am just about to graduate. Thus I could need the job and the employer told me in  the second interview that I wont be able to get a job anywhere else

Comment: An employer does not does this. Well a legitimate one. You are far more better than this company.

Comment: So they thought they had the money and then found out they didn't? Sounds like they need to fire their accountant. It also sounds like they aren't doing well financially. I would try to find something more stable.

Comment: "* they said they dont really need me but are just agreeing to keep me in board in somewhat of a good will gesture*"  I'd find that a particularly hard statement to take in good faith : companies just do not do these kind of things.  Don't get sucked into this mess.

Answer (score 4):

Either they're engaging in some really shady negotiation tactics, or it really is just a good-will gesture (likely with a hint of a giant organisational mess).

In the latter case, there's a small chance that you'll find a good role there eventually, but the best option in either case is probably just to follow their advice and find another job.

Answer (score 0):

So they didn't have their ducks in a row before hiring you.  Not only was the expenditure not approved, but they determined that they don't need you.

If I were you, I wouldn't take this job unless you're not working now and just need the money.  If you're working now and take the job, you'd be entering a situation where its reputation with you is already less than good, and maybe leaving a situation that's more stable than where you're going.

In either case if you take it, it may hinder you from having the time to get the job you *do* want.  Whatever the case, don't fool yourself into relying too heavily on this opportunity.  If you can't get a written offer, don't bother!!

Answer (score 0):

They probably run out of budget, or just found a better candidate. So they are basically suggesting you to move on.

I think they are being honest with their second proposal (it may just be an internship, and that would explain the reduced salary). However, given how things have happened, I would just thanks them for your offer and look for something else - it cannot be as hard as they are implying.

Answer (score 0):

Do not work for this company. I am not familiar with the specifics of why the company reduced your offer, but the last line in your question is troubling to say the least.

> the employer told me in the second interview that I wont be able to
> get a job anywhere else

No reputable or honest company should or would ever say that to a candidate. I also do not believe that they do not have the money to hire you as per the original promised amount. The first step of the hiring process besides who you want to hire is how much you can afford to pay them (employers always have a salary ceiling for a job role). If they're being honest, then it sounds like a poorly run company and one you probably shouldn't work for.

**There are numerous red flags in your question:**

> - They also said that if I find another job I should go for it
> - they said that they did not get the permission for what they originally offered

You might need the job, but I have a feeling you'll probably regret it. If you can hold on for a while longer, I am sure something more suitable will come up for you.